# Search filter for nested json array using Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I am trying to filter a nested json array using Knockout js. Here is how my JSON looks

```
{
"groups": [{
    "name": "Category1",
    "items": [{
        "question": "Question1",
        "answer": "Answer1"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Category2",
    "items": [{
        "question": "Question2",
        "answer": "Answer2"
    }, {
        "question": "Question3",
        "answer": "Answer3"
    }]
  }]
}
```

I need to filter based on the "answer". Here is how my HTML page looks right now

```
 <div >
<div class="groups" data-bind="{foreach: {data: filteredGroups, as: 'group'}}">
  <div class="name-row" data-bind="text: group.name"></div>
  <div class="items" data-bind="{foreach: {data: group.items, as: 'item'}}">
    <div class="item-row">
      <div class="question-row">
        <div class="question-content">
          <div class="letter">Question</div>
          <div data-bind="text: item.question"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="notch">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="answer-row">
        <div class="letter">Answer</div>
        <div data-bind="text: item.answer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is my current logic:

```
 self.filteredGroups = ko.computed(function() {
  if (!self.query()) {
    return self.groups();
  }
  else {  

       var matchCount = 0;

      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.groups(), function(group) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(group.items, function(item) { 
           //console.log("Entered==>" + self.query().toLowerCase() +  "  "  + "Search==>" + item.question.toLowerCase());
           var found = item.answer.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.query().toLowerCase());
           if(found >= 0){
             console.log("Number of occurrences" +matchCount++);
             return true;
           }else{
             return false;
           }
         });
      });

   }
});
```

However, when I tried executing the same I do not get filtered result. Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to filter items with keeping their groups. In your solution inner `arrayFilter` will always return an array of filtered items. But as you may know any array (even empty) always will evaluate to `true` causing the outer `arrayFilter` to return *all* original group objects with *all* original items, because filtered items were lost due to implicit type conversion.

The simplest way to get your `computed` working:

```
self.filteredGroups = ko.computed(function() {
    if (!self.query()) {
        return self.groups();
    } else {

        var result = [];

        // for each group
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.groups(), function(group){

            // find items matching the query
            var items = ko.utils.arrayFilter(group.items, function(item){
                return item.answer.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.query()) >= 0;
            }); console.log(items);

            // if found something then push new group object with filtered items
            if (items.length > 0) result.push({
                name: group.name,
                items: items
            });

        });

        return result;
    }
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83qcmgka/)